# Javascript - How to reverse a string and disappear those commas?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to reverse the string like this: `"How are you"` -> `"you are How"`
Those are the code I typed, it could reverse the string , 
but it still has comma between strings like `"you,are,How"`

```
var str = window.prompt("Enter a string");
var tokens = str.split( " " );


document.writeln( tokens.reverse() );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **.join(" ")**

```
var str = window.prompt("Enter a string"); var tokens = str.split( " " );
document.writeln( tokens.reverse().join(" ") );
```